# Designing a random number generator

Tags: random, probability

I am trying to design a random number generator which generates random numbers from 0-11.But I need to design that considering I already have a random number generator which generates random number from 0-5.All the numbers from 0-11 should be generated with equal probability.

I went through this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-integer-from-1-to-7-with-equal-probability/)

In the link the equation used is `5*foo() + foo() -5` wherein `foo()` generates number 1-5 (not 0-5)

```
1. For each value of first foo(), there can be 5 possible combinations for values of second foo(). So, there are total 25 combinations possible.
2. The range of values returned by the above equation is 1 to 25, each integer occurring exactly once.
3. If the value of the equation comes out to be less than 22, return modulo division by 7 followed by adding 1. Else, again call the method recursively. The probability of returning each integer thus becomes 1/7.
```

Now can i change the function which modulus it by 12 and recurse the function if the number surpasses 24, in the function which is defined in the link above?If not then I am not understanding what is wrong.

Alternatively I came upon this one

lets call the random number generator function `f(6)` which generates number 0-5.

```
(f(6)+f(6)+f(6))%12;
```

If not what alternative solution can i deduct?I need help in doing this task.Maybe I am missing something.The catch here is each number between 0-11 should have equal probability of generation.Other than `f(6)` I cannot use any other function.Only mathematical manipulations.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Please read [ask]. Your post should be improved in two directions: Include the linked resource relevant sections in your post (in case the resource is moved or deleted), and provide the code of your current attempt. Good luck!

Comment: is this good?I dont need a code, I have provided what I attempted...tried my best but still I think I am missing something.

Comment: What you're doing sounds reasonable but I'll leave it to someone who can _prove_ it. I'm rusty and the classes I took about it were a while ago.

Comment: Hint: given your function, how would you generate numbers between 0 and 35 (so 36 distinct possibilities) with equal probability?  Try adjusting the equation from your first link.  (`(f(6) + f(6) + f(6)) %12` is not what you want: it's not going to give you a uniform distribution.)

Comment: @Mark `5*f(6)+f(6)+f(6)`...still far from uniformity

Comment: @Ayush: close, but not quite.  Note that with just *two* calls to `f(6)`, you're already getting 6 * 6 = 36 possible different outcomes (and conveniently, 36 is a multiple of 12).  Now you just have to find a way to map those distinct outcomes to what you want.

Comment: oh so `f(6)*f(6)%12` should do the task?

Comment: @DarioP will this ensure equal probability?

Comment: @Ayush: the `(f(6)+1) * (f(6)+1)) % 12` suggestion certainly doesn't give a uniform distribution (for example, `7` doesn't come up at all).  @DarioP's second suggestion does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but in this case I would go for:

```
f(6) + 6*f(2)
```

where

```
f(2) = f(6)%2
```

The probability is uniform because you have a uniform probability to obtain a number from 0 to 5, and a uniform probability to shift it to the 6-11 interval.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your 0..5 generator g6(). If you calculate (6 * g6()) + g6(), that will give you a uniform 0..35. Now just divide by 3, and you'll have a uniform 0..11.